# How to interprete this きた

Tags: grammar

The following sentence stands isolated:

昔から川を治める者が国をよく治めると言われてきた。

"From olden days we are told that the persons who rule the river(s) often rule the country."

I guess this きた expresses that something comes to me/us here?
I didn't encounter it in a temporal function yet, only in spatial semantics so far. Thats why I wanted to ask about it.

Comment: "言われてきた。... **we** are told that..." <- It's " **it** has been told **that** ...", right? The doer of the action 言う is we/people, no?

Comment: @Chocolate "It has been told that" sounds a little strange". "It has been said that" would be better. What is the problem with "We have been told that"? I can't understand why the pronoun "it" is better than "we" here.

Comment: @user3856370 そうですね、"It has been said that..." がいいと思います。 Here, it doesn't mean "We have been told..." or 私たちが(誰かに)言われてきた, since the subject of 言われる (to be said) is not "we/人々/我々" but what has been said, i.e. 「川を治める者が国をよく治める」. The active voice 「昔から、人々は『川を治める者が国をよく治める』と言ってきた」 is turned into the passive voice 「昔から、『川を治める者が国をよく治める』と（人々によって）言われてきた」.

Comment: (cont.) "Since early times, it has been said that the one who rules the river(s) rules the country well." It's **not** the passive form of 「昔から、人々は『川を治める者が国をよく治める』と**我々に**言ってきた」.  By the way, @Narktor, the よく is not "often" but "well, successfully (上手に、うまく)."

Answer (score 2):

> From olden days we **are told** that the persons who rule the river(s) often rule the country."

is translated as:
昔から川を治める者が国をよく治めると**言われている。**

And

> 昔から川を治める者が国をよく治めると**言われてきた**。

is translated as:

From olden days we **have been told** that the persons who rule the river(s) often rule the country."

きた in this context indicates the continuation from the past to the present.

Comment: Where do you get "we" from?

Comment: I got the "we" from the original poster's translation. I respect their translation and tried to make the least change to their original translation. And I agree with their translation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think of 言われてきた as "it has come to be said".

Comment: `it has come to be said` <- それって「言われるようになった」とかじゃないんですかね・・

Comment: その通りはより正確でしょうね　。